# Outliers Detection in Sentinel Bands

Tags: python, detection, outliers, sentinel

I have tifs of Sentinel bands for a specific tile, I have already implemented cloudmasking. I should now create an RGB in 8bit, but first I have to reduce outliers in my images and reduce gaussian noise. I am really confused in the process of reducing outliers, normalizing, rescaling images. I am working on Python and a snippet of my code is:

```
# Use of cloudmasked images from previous exercise
denoised_imgs = {}

for band, values in cloudfree.items():
    print(f'band max is {values.max()} and min is {values.min()}')

    # Outlier Detection
    mean_val = np.mean(values)
    print(f'mean: {mean_val}')
    std_val = np.std(values)
    print(f'std: {std_val}')
    z_scores = (values - mean_val) / std_val

    thershold = 2
    outlier_mask  = np.abs(z_scores) > thershold

    values[outlier_mask] = mean_val

    rescaled = np.clip(values, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

    min_val = np.min(values)
    max_val = np.max(values)
    normalized_data = ((values - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)) * 255
    
    # Reduce Gaussian Blur
    # img_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(clipped_band, 9, 5, 5)

    denoised_imgs[band] = normalized_data

# Stack RGB-denoised
rgb_denoised = np.dstack([denoised_imgs['B04'], denoised_imgs['B03'], denoised_imgs['B02']])
cropped_denoised = rgb_denoised[uly_pixel:lry_pixel, ulx_pixel:lrx_pixel]
```

cloudfree: dictionary where keys are the band names and values the arrays of image (values.dtype('uint16'))

Thanks!
L.

I am trying to figure out outliers detection methods in python.
I am using these libraries, and i would prefer to stick with them for now. But I am open to suggestions of other libraries for future studying.

```
# Import libraries
from pathlib import Path
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Could you provide a working piece of code with data (small if possible), and explain exactly where is the error ? and/or precise problem ? So we can understand, test and help better. See [MRE].

Comment: Hello! thanks :) do you want all my code? this part i shared is my problem. it works but it gives wrong results. So I suppose there is something wrong with the order I have the commands? or the data I use?

Comment: Best is to try to show a working small piece of code we can run ourselves (working by itself but keep it as small/shorten it as needed to work and show your issue), then show error messages / erroneous output .. and tell us what was expected instead? look a the link [MRE] to get the idea. For now i cannot run your code and have no idea of whats is going wrong. This si needed so you may have help.